# Defining polymorphic constants in Haskell

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

I've read about polymorphic constants/nullary polymorphic functions [in Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses). It gave several examples of built-in ones, such as:

```
ghci> 20 :: Float  
20.0  
ghci> 20 :: Int  
20  
ghci> minBound :: Int  
-2147483648  
ghci> maxBound :: (Bool, Int, Char)  
(True,2147483647,'\1114111')
```

However, it does not explain how to define your own. How are they defined?

Comment: `mempty` is another example of a polymorphic constant.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to make a typeclass including the functions/constants you want, each with a variable return type. Instantiate it for each type you want your constants to be able to be.

```
class MyConstants a where
  one :: a
  ten :: a

instance MyConstants Int where
  one = 1
  ten = 10

instance MyConstants Float where
  one = 1.0
  ten = 10.0

instance MyConstants String where
  one = "one"
  ten = "ten"
```

#### Example Usage ([codepad](http://codepad.org/WXVXxOve))

```
main = do
  putStrLn . show $ (ten :: Int)
  putStrLn . show $ (one :: String)
  putStrLn . show $ (ten :: Float) + one
  putStrLn . show $ "Count from " ++ one ++ " to " ++ ten
```

```
10
"one"
11.0
"Count from one to ten"
```

Comment: Preserving opening comment: *...or you could define a variable in terms of other, existing polymorphic constants. For example, one = 1 :: Num x => x.* and thread was moved to chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7336/values-and-functions-in-haskell-oh-my - sorry Jeremy don't really have time to individually delete around certain comments. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 5):

First, I recommend against using the term "constant" to mean non-functions, since all values are constant (immutable), whether those values are functions (i.e. have function type) or not.

You don't even need type classes to have polymorphic non-functions. An example is `[]`. To define your own polymorphic non-functions, you can define a data type (as in the list example) or construct something out of already-defined pieces. For instance: `empties = ([],[[]])`.